# how to decode dbus.Array fromat to hex or string in python

Tags: python-3.x, dbus

How to decode:

```
dbus.Array([dbus.Byte(1), dbus.Byte(35)], signature=dbus.Signature('y'))
```

to **HEX** or **String** in Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you want to do is to convert it to bytes; below you can see how I used to write it to a binary file.

```
    localFile = open ('/home/youruser/data.bin', 'wb')
    try:
        for byteValue in arrayValue:
            localFile.write(chr(byteValue))
    finally:
        localFile.close()
```

Answer (score 8):

As the [DBus specification](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html) says, `y` means byte.
So `dbus.Array([...], signature=dbus.Signature('y'))` is an array of bytes.

Let's consider this value:

```
value = dbus.Array([dbus.Byte(76), dbus.Byte(97), dbus.Byte(98), dbus.Byte(65), dbus.Byte(80), dbus.Byte(97), dbus.Byte(114), dbus.Byte(116)], signature=dbus.Signature('y'))
```

- If you know your value contains a **string**:

  ```
  print("value:%s" % ''.join([str(v) for v in value]))
  # Will print 'value:LabAPart'
  ```
- **For an array of byte:**

  ```
  print("value:%s" % [bytes([v]) for v in value])
  # Will print 'value:[b'L', b'a', b'b', b'A', b'P', b'a', b'r', b't']'
  ```
- **For an array of integer:**

  ```
  print("value:%s" % [int(v) for v in value])
  # Will print 'value:[76, 97, 98, 65, 80, 97, 114, 116]'
  ```

Comment: Your 1st option will only work for ASCII; it'll quickly break with multi-byte UTF-8 characters. Try `bytes(value).decode()` instead. Your 3rd option is practically equivalent to `bytes(value)` alone.